# Symfony 2 Attempted to load class " " from namespace " " Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

I am trying to use the Entity Philip  inside a Symfony Controller

But this error Showing when i want to load the route:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCyRM.png)

> Attempted to load class “PhilipRepositroy ” from namespace
>   “AppBundle\Repository ” Did you forget a “use” statement for another
>   namespace?

**My Controller**

```
 /**
 * @Route("/see", name="see")
 */
public function SeeAction()
{
    $Philip = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Philip')
        ->findAll();

    return $this->render('business/see.html.twig', array(
        'Philip' => $Philip
    ));
}
```

**My Philip Entity**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Philip
 */
class Philip
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $philipname;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $philipemail;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $philipphone;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $philipregion;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $philipville;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $philipcin;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $philipcv;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $philipgender;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set philipname
     *
     * @param string $philipname
     * @return Philip
     */
    public function setPhilipname($philipname)
    {
        $this->philipname = $philipname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get philipname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhilipname()
    {
        return $this->philipname;
    }

    /**
     * Set philipemail
     *
     * @param string $philipemail
     * @return Philip
     */
    public function setPhilipemail($philipemail)
    {
        $this->philipemail = $philipemail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get philipemail
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhilipemail()
    {
        return $this->philipemail;
    }

    /**
     * Set philipphone
     *
     * @param string $philipphone
     * @return Philip
     */
    public function setPhilipphone($philipphone)
    {
        $this->philipphone = $philipphone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get philipphone
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhilipphone()
    {
        return $this->philipphone;
    }

    /**
     * Set philipregion
     *
     * @param string $philipregion
     * @return Philip
     */
    public function setPhilipregion($philipregion)
    {
        $this->philipregion = $philipregion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get philipregion
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhilipregion()
    {
        return $this->philipregion;
    }

    /**
     * Set philipville
     *
     * @param string $philipville
     * @return Philip
     */
    public function setPhilipville($philipville)
    {
        $this->philipville = $philipville;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get philipville
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhilipville()
    {
        return $this->philipville;
    }

    /**
     * Set philipcin
     *
     * @param string $philipcin
     * @return Philip
     */
    public function setPhilipcin($philipcin)
    {
        $this->philipcin = $philipcin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get philipcin
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhilipcin()
    {
        return $this->philipcin;
    }

    /**
     * Set philipcv
     *
     * @param string $philipcv
     * @return Philip
     */
    public function setPhilipcv($philipcv)
    {
        $this->philipcv = $philipcv;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get philipcv
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhilipcv()
    {
        return $this->philipcv;
    }

    /**
     * Set philipgender
     *
     * @param string $philipgender
     * @return Philip
     */
    public function setPhilipgender($philipgender)
    {
        $this->philipgender = $philipgender;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get philipgender
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhilipgender()
    {
        return $this->philipgender;
    }
}
```

**My PhilipRepository**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * PhilipRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class PhilipRepository extends EntityRepository
{
}
```

What i can do to resolve this problem? I am new to Symfony

Comment: What's the point of a custom repository when it doesn't contain any custom functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess you failed to get Repository class? Then in your `Philip` entity class add mappings

```
   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

   /**
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PhilipRepository")
    */
    class Philip
    {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: i add this line and nothing Changed , same problem appear , thank you

Comment: did you cleared cache? `php bin/console cache:clear` symfony command, or manually from `var/cache` directory?

Comment: Yes i try this also :) Thank you 
the problem resolved Just in PhilipReposity i change this line: 
class PhilipRepository extends EntityRepository
 by this Line : ( class PhiliRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository )

Comment: Specifying full path isn't necessary since you have `use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;` so it should work with `PhilipRepository extends EntityRepository` as well.

Comment: This may be stranger , How ? i don't know 
BTW i dont change any word in my code only  specifying full path and remove the use